# What can be the rank of the following matrix, where $a$ is a parameter?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

The matrix is $
A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
  a & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1  & 3 & -3  \\
  4 & 2 & 0 & a
 \end{pmatrix}$

I have "tested" the matrix and I always get that the rank of the matrix is 4. How can I show that after the Gauss Elimination the number of linearly independent rows will be always 4?

Comment: The matrix has full rank if and only if the determinant is nonzero. But the determinant is $-2(a-3)^2$.

Comment: akeet has pointed you the way.  find the determinant.  It will be a quadratic.  If the roots are complex then there is no real $a$ such that the rank will be less than 4.  (but there would still be complex $a$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is equal to the dimensión of the row space.

since the determinant is $-2(a-3)^2$ we conclude the rank is $4$ is $a\neq 2$.

Otherwise rows $2$ and $4$ are in the span of columns $1$ and $3$, so the rank is $3$

Comment: and how can I fast get the value of the determinant?

Comment: @Zauberkerl Probably the fastest way without a computer is to do row/column operations and try to rack up a bunch of zeros.

Comment: the rank will be $2$ if $a=3$

Comment: Sorry about that.